# Pytest fixture scope not respected in Visual Studio Code debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I have defined a pytest fixture which I request from a parametrized test function. The fixture is marked with scope "session", so it should return the same object each time.

```
class DemoClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = id(self)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def instance():
    return DemoClass()

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "run",
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
)
def test_demo(run, instance):
    print(f"run {run}: {instance.id}")
```

Now, when I run pytest from the terminal, it works as expected:

```
collected 5 items                                                                                                                                

tests\test_demo.py 
run 1: 2727993418448
run 2: 2727993418448
run 3: 2727993418448
run 4: 2727993418448
run 5: 2727993418448
```

But, when I click the little debug icon in Visual Studio Code, each test iteration will return a different object and the run order is random:

```
run 5: 1829477782672
run 3: 2193585018000
run 4: 2162028647568
run 2: 1836194796688
run 1: 2310279959696
```

Is this expected? Is there a way to make the Visual Studio Code pytest integration respect the scope?